# Question about Cesàro summation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, summation, cesaro-summable

Consider $$S_n = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i$$
and its Cesàro sums, defined as
$$ C = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n S_k$$
Is it always true that
$$ C = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{L(n)}\sum_{k= n - L(n)}^n S_k$$
where $L(n)$ is any strictly increasing function such that $ 2 < L(n) < \ln(n)$ for every $n$?

Comment: @User1952009 i think i wrote what i meant ?

Comment: Yes sorry , i edited

Comment: tell it to ClementC. Also do you have a precise $a_n$ in mind, or do you assume something about it an $S_n$, for example $O(1)$ or $O(n)$  ?

Comment: No specific a_n no. I wonder if it ALWAYS holds ; for all a_n.

Comment: Did you try things like $a_n = cos(\ln n) $ and $L(n) = 2$ ?

Comment: This cannot hold. Try $a_n=1$ if $n=3^k-k$ and $a_n=-1$ if $a_n=3^k$, for some $k\geqslant1$, thus the first terms of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ are $0|0|1|-1|0|0|0|1|0|-1|0$ and $S_n=1$ if $3^k-k\leqslant n<3^k$ for some $k\geqslant1$ while $S_n=0$ for every other $n$. In particular, $(S_n)$ is Cesaro summable with $C=0$ but, for $$L(n)=\lfloor\log_3(n)\rfloor$$ the ratios $$\frac1{L(n)}\sum_{k=n-L(n)}^nS_k$$ fluctuate between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @Did: I included your comment (with attribution) in my answer -- is that alright?

Comment: @ClementC. Sure. (Maybe concentrate your post on its most relevant parts and eliminate everything else?)

Comment: @Did Thanks -- done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** no.

---

Define for convenience $L(n)$; by assumption, we have $L(n)=o(n)$ as $n\to\infty$.

- Note that if $L(n)$ is bounded, then this is clearly *false* as the few missing constant terms do not  really matter: you cannot hope that $\sum_{k=0}^n S_k$ be bounded in general (that is, there are Cesàro summable sums which are not convergent in the usual summation sense). For instance, take $a_n=(-1)^n$.
- Assuming now $L(n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$, this looks like you are wondering about some specific converse of the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

However, as [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did)'s comment above shows, this is still *false* even with this assumption: I reproduced this comment below:

> This cannot hold. Try $a_n=1$ if $n=3^k-k$ and $a_n=-1$ if $a_n=3^k$, for some $k\geqslant1$, thus the first terms of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ are $0|0|1|-1|0|0|0|1|0|-1|0$ and $S_n=1$ if $3^k-k\leqslant n<3^k$ for some $k\geqslant1$ while $S_n=0$ for every other $n$. In particular, $(S_n)$ is Cesàro-summable with $C=0$ but, for
>   $$L(n)=\lfloor\log_3(n)\rfloor$$
>   the ratios
>   $$\frac1{L(n)}\sum_{k=n-L(n)}^nS_k$$
>   fluctuate between 0 and 1.

Comment: I edited the question , sorry i made a mistake

Comment: I see. Let me edit my answer, then.

Comment: @mick I have to go, and my new "answer" is incomplete. Maybe someone will drop by and finish it.

Comment: Tl;dr : no , what is that ??

Comment: "Too long; didn't read: no" ("if you don't have time to read the proof, here is the answer: no").

Comment: Is the answer finished now ??

Comment: Yes, it is. ${}$